# Is there a way to help a stunted Euonymus europaeus grow more?

Tags: plant-care, shrubs

I have an *Euonymus europaeus*.

However, it appears its growth is stunted - it consists of only one weak looking main branch (I really can't call it a trunk) with several smaller branches.

There is no visible damage, or illness. It is just so small.

How can I help this bush achieve its full potential?

This is a picture from wikimedia of a full grown euonymus:

[image]

[https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Argentr%C3%A9-du-Plessis_-_Euonymus_europaeus_-*20111104*(2).JPG](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Argentr%C3%A9-du-Plessis_-_Euonymus_europaeus_-_20111104_(2).JPG)

Just imagine 1/30th of the bush in the picture - that is my bush.

I should say that it is situated in part shade area.

Note: I know there is a similar question: [Best help for a tree with stunted growth?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/110/best-help-for-a-tree-with-stunted-growth) I hope I can get more advice specific to this bush.

Should I perhaps cut it to the ground? Or only add some natural fertilizer?

Comment: It is a strange plant. On books it is written that it can growth like trees (10 meters). Personally I have some large shrubs, but other shrubs remain small. It doesn't depend on exposition or climate. I think there is no difference in fertilizers (none in last 20 years). So I'm curios on the answers [I assumed it is just variance between individuals, or she is a plant who really like to have the right mycorrhiza]

Comment: How long have you had the shrub and what conditions is it growing in, in terms of soil, moisture, sunlight/shade?

Comment: It is a 9 years old shrub, soil is clay, normally drained, neutral pH, part shadow (more precisely, only half a day dappled shade, and the rest is more or less full shade). It flowers and has fruit. @Bamboo

Comment: Nearby trees are an Acer pseudoplatanus, a Mespilus germanica, and a Malus pumila. Nearby bush is a Viburnum opulus. All trees are fine, viburnum is perhaps a little smaller than usual for its species, still a giant compared to the euonymus. @Bamboo

Comment: Can we not have a photo of this shrub's situation, showing it and the surrounding area (not too wide an area though)? Soil  where it is doesn't get waterlogged or very damp?

Comment: Photo  - I am not able to get it at this moment. Soil - it is a little hill/slope, I don't recall any excess water at any time there. @Bamboo

Comment: Can you add a source link for the photo you have here? I know you said it's from wikimedia, but as far as I know we're supposed to add a link to the exact wikimedia page. If I'm wrong about that, I hope someone will correct me! Thanks!

Comment: @Sue I added the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late answer;

This is a plant that thrives in full sun it will be stunted if grown in full shade, even if that shade it dappled shade is still shade.  It will grow in part shade, meaning less than 6 hours of direct sunlight, but still getting at least 3 hours of direct sun.  It will grow in that kind of sun light, but not thrive.

The plant in the picture is thriving in full sun.  Your plant is not able to make the energy to grow.  Some plants have leaves that are adapted at collecting sunlight in a shaded location, but many plants do not have this adaptation and require higher amount of sunlight to thrive.

I would dig it and move it to a full sun location.  I would do this in the fall.  Plants may not be growing above ground in winter, but roots will still grow as long as the ground is not frozen.  If your summers do not get enough rain in summer you will probably have to give it additional water the first two summers after moving it.

The link from Missouri Botanical calls it an invasive weed and not to plant it.  Whether it is invasive depends on where you live in the world.  Obviously it is invasive in US Midwest.

[Euonymus europaeus Missouri Botainical](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?taxonid=279118)